# bash & mingw: overwrites output when scrolling up

Tags: bash, mingw, msysgit

I'm currently using git-for-windows-sdk, with Bash `3.1.33(1)-release`. I experience quite annoying and buggy behavior when I scroll up and press `key up`: Console doesn't scroll back to bottom, just shows the prompt and starts overwriting output.

Clearing helps just for the currently shown area, after outputting goes next, there is still buffered output.

**How to reproduce:**

1. Output something longer than 1 screen.
2. Scroll up.
3. Press `arrow up` key.

**Expected behavior:**

Bash scrolls down and shows prompt.

**Current behavior:**

Bash stays on the screen and shows prompt on the last line. Then overwrites buffered output.

---

Actually, I tried to investigate this behavior a little bit. And I realized, that it's affected by `PS1`/`PROMPT` setting. Color escapes and new lines have some role in it, but I was unable to define it.

- the default git-bash prompt setting **doesn't produce** this wrong behavior:

  ```
  export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\n\[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[0m\]\[\033[32m\]" "\[\033[0m\]\n$ "'
  ```
- just removing the new line **produces** wrong behavior:

  ```
  export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\n\[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[0m\]\[\033[32m\]" "\[\033[0m\]$ "'
  ```
- however, one line prompt without colors **doesn't produce** wrong behavior:

  ```
  export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\w" " \$ "'
  ```

---

For better understanding see this screencast: http://screencast.com/t/vqItWFSoR